# Python: Datetime. Converting Users input into MM/YY

Tags: python

So i'm wondering if anyone knows how to take the users input (MM/YY) and check that against todays date then output invalid if the month and year matches todays values and vice versa. i know how to check dates but i don't know how to do it with just the month and the year. e.g. 03/21

Code:

```py
    loyaltyexpiry = input("Enter your loyalty card expiry date (MM/YY): ")
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    date_today=datetime.date(now.year, now.month, now.day)


   
    if loyaltyexpiry > str(date_today):
      digitcheck = int(loyaltynum[7])
    
      reverse = loyaltynum[6] + loyaltynum[5] + loyaltynum[4] + loyaltynum[3] + loyaltynum[2] + loyaltynum[1] + loyaltynum[0]
      num1 = reverse[0]
      num3 = reverse[2]
      num5 = reverse[4]
      num7 = reverse[6]

      num1 = int(reverse[0]) * 2
      num3 = int(reverse[2]) * 2
      num5 = int(reverse[4]) * 2
      num7 = int(reverse[6]) * 2

      if num1 > 9:
          num1 = num1 - 9
    
      if num3 > 9:
          num3 = num3 - 9
    
      if num5 > 9:
          num5 = num5 - 9
    
      if num7 > 9:
          num7 = num7 - 9
    
      overall = num1 + int(reverse[1]) + num3 + int(reverse[3]) + num5 + int(reverse[5]) + num7
      overall = overall + digitcheck

      if overall % 10 == 0:
           print(Fore.GREEN + "\nLoyalty Card Valid")
      else:
           print(Fore.RED + "\nLoyalty Card Invalid")    
            
    else:
         print(Fore.RED + "\nLoyalty Card Expired")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) to parse and compare:

```py
from datetime import datetime, date

now = datetime.now()
now = date(year=now.year, month=now.month, day=1)

loyalty_expiry = input("Enter your loyalty card expiry date (MM/YY): ")
expiry = datetime.strptime(loyalty_expiry, "%m/%y")
expiry = date(year=expiry.year, month=expiry.month, day=1)

print(now, expiry, sep="\n")

if now == expiry:
    print("year and month match")
elif now > expiry:
    print("expired")
elif now < expiry:
    print("not expired")
```

Which outputs:

```
Enter your loyalty card expiry date (MM/YY): 12/99
2021-03-01
1999-12-01
expired

Enter your loyalty card expiry date (MM/YY): 03/21
2021-03-01
2021-03-01
year and month match

Enter your loyalty card expiry date (MM/YY): 12/26
2021-03-01
2026-12-01
not expired
```

Comment: how would i go about making this so if the inputted date/month is greater than the current date/month it executes codes but then if it is the same as the current month it prints
```

Comment: You can modify the `if` statement to reflect what you want, something like: `elif expiry.month > now.month and expiry.year >= now.year`

Comment: probably being completely wrong however i've added this. it works if the year is 02/21 and 02/22 but if i enter 04/21 it gives off invalid which it should because we are on this year. (i know i'm being stupid sorry
`if expiry.month >= now.month and expiry.year > now.year:
     print("great")
 elif expiry.month <= now.month and expiry.year > now.year:
     print("great")
 else:
  print("invalid")`

Comment: I've updated my answer to use `datetime.date` which makes the comparisons easier. Let me know if it doesn't make sense

Comment: nope that is fine. i've implemented it into the way i want now. thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt
today = dt.now()
print(f"today is: {today.month:02}/{-2000 + today.year:02}")

if "03/21" == f"{today.month:02}/{-2000 + today.year:02}":
    print("match")
```